# How to assume some variables to "not" be a function of other variables at the time of defining a function

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, function-construction, assumptions

I have a function with the following definition:

`F[x]=Exp[q*w*x];`

I want to take total derivatives of F.

How can I define that q and w are not dependent on x at the time of defining F in order to avoid repeating this assumption in each calculation of derivatives?

Comment: From the second bullet point under "Details and Options" in the documentation of the total derivative operator [`Dt`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Dt.html): "Symbols with attribute `Constant` are taken to be constants, with zero total derivative." The first bullet point gives another alternative that seems less convenient in this use-case as I understand it.

Answer (score 3):

You may give q and w the attribute "Constant".

Here is an example:

```
Clear["Global`*"]
SetAttributes[{q, w}, Constant]
F[x_] = Exp[q*w*x];
Dt[F[x]]
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
F[x_] = Exp[q*w*x];
```

The partial derivative w.r.t. `x`

```
F'[x]

(* E^(q w x) q w *)
```

or

```
D[F[x], x]

(* E^(q w x) q w *)
```

The total derivative

```
Dt[F[x]]

(* E^(q w x) (w x Dt[q] + q x Dt[w] + q w Dt[x]) *)

%//TraditionalForm
```

[image]